# Weierstrass M-Test: Show that the series is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, continuity, power-series

Please show that $f$ is differentiable over any interval of the type $(a,\infty)$ with $a>0$.

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^6x^2}. $$

Attempt:
I figured that since we are on Chapter 7 in Rudin now covering sequences of functions and series, I should use the Weierstrass M-test.

So I took the derivative of $f$, and found $f'(x)$ to be $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2k^6x}{(1+k^6x^2)^2} $$.  Note I think the lower bound of the sum may start from 2 instead of 1 (not sure).  Anyway, I try to bound this so that I can use the Weierstrass M-Test.  I get: $$|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2k^6x}{(1+k^6x^2)^2}| \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{2k^6x}{(1+k^6a^2)^2}$$.

The problem is I don't know how to get a bound for the top.  I have this x on the top and I want my bound or $M_n$ to not depend on x. This is the part , I get stuck on.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.  I know that once I get my $M_n$ , I have to show my series of $M_n$'s converges.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\frac{2k^6x}{(1+k^6x^2)^2}=\frac{2k^6}{x^{-1}+2k^6x+k^{12}x^3}
$$
and that
$$
x^{-1}+2k^6x\ge 2\sqrt{2}k^3>0
$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{2k^6x}{(1+k^6x^2)^2}\le\frac{2k^6}{k^{12}x^3}\le\frac{2}{a^3k^{6}}$$

Comment: So basically in order to get a greater than or equal to, you make the denominator smaller by removing the first two terms in the expression which has three terms (keep only k^12x^3)?

Comment: @rain Yeah, it also could be done by noting that $1+k^6x^2>k^6x^2$.